# Switching Chapter and Section titles

Tags: sectioning, chapters, sections-paragraphs

I am somewhat new to TEX and I am writing a book using a publishing framework which uses Xelatex and `polyglossia`.  My book is divided into three major sections or sub-books and each sub-book is divided into multiple chapters.

The class puts "Chapter 1" for what I want to be "Section 1".  Any idea of a fix for which I can switch Chapter to Section?

Comment: use `\part` for the sub-book, that is the heading level above `\chapter` then define `\partname` to be section if you don't want it called part

Comment: And this has nothing to do with `polyglossia` but with your `\documentclass`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the edits!  So found the solution.  Turns out softcover.io uses polyTex and I have to use @DavidCarlisle 's suggestion and follow the build instructions outlined in chapter six of softcover.io's [manual](http://manual.softcover.io/book/polytex_tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\part` for the sub-book, that is the heading level above `\chapter` then define `\partname` to be section if you don't want it called part.